# Integration by substitution of an improper integral, where did I go wrong?

Tags: integration, substitution

Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \beta\cdot \frac{1}{x^{\beta+1}}$ with $\beta > 0$

Asked for is the following integral: $\displaystyle \int_1^\infty f(x) \quad dx$

Now I wanted to use integration by substitution with the inverse of $f$,  $f^{-1}(x)$.
 (By defining $f: (0,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ the functions should match the prerequisites.)

Here's the equality for integration by substitution (from Wiki):

$\displaystyle
\int_{a}^{b} f(\varphi(t)) \cdot \varphi'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = \int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(b)} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x $

I now set $\,\,\varphi = f^{-1}$.

$\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} f(f^{-1}(t)) \cdot \big(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} f^{-1}(t)\big)\,\mathrm{d}t = \int_{f^{-1}(a)}^{f^{-1}(b)} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x $

$\Leftrightarrow$

$\displaystyle \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}t \cdot \big(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} f^{-1}(t)\big)\,\mathrm{d}t = \int_{a}^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x $

However, when I now try to use the result on my problem, $f(\infty)$ tends to $0$, making it an integral $\displaystyle \int_1^0...$, which results in $0$, but should result in $1$.

Comment: Why isn't this just the power rule?

Comment: That one is working, true. I just want to know where this method fails, integration by the differenciation of the inverse sounds useful enough to want to know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f^{-1}(t)=\beta^{1/(\beta+1)}t^{-1/(\beta+1)}$, so $\dfrac{d}{dt}f^{-1}(t)=-\beta^{1/(\beta+1)}\dfrac{1}{\beta+1}t^{-1/(\beta+1)-1}$, there is a negative sign here, so 
\begin{align*}
\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}t\cdot\dfrac{d}{dt}f^{-1}(t)dt&=\int_{\beta}^{0}t\cdot-\beta^{1/(\beta+1)}\dfrac{1}{\beta+1}t^{-1/(\beta+1)-1}dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{\beta}t\cdot\beta^{1/(\beta+1)}\dfrac{1}{\beta+1}t^{-1/(\beta+1)-1}dt\\
&=\dfrac{\beta^{1/(\beta+1)}}{\beta+1}\int_{0}^{\beta}t^{-1/(\beta+1)}dt\\
&=\dfrac{\beta^{1/(\beta+1)}}{\beta+1}\dfrac{1}{1-1/(\beta+1)}t^{1-1/(\beta+1)}\bigg|_{t=0}^{t=\beta}\\
&=\dfrac{\beta^{1/(\beta+1)}}{\beta+1}\dfrac{\beta^{1-1/(\beta+1)}}{1-1/(\beta+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{\beta}{\beta+1-1}\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Comment: Why is it allowed to swap the integral around by negating the term right to it?

Comment: Here is the formula: $-\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f(u)du=\displaystyle\int_{b}^{a}f(u)du$.

Comment: We define $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f(u)du=-\displaystyle\int_{b}^{a}f(u)du$ for $a>b$.